# Slow performance in hashing images in Python

Tags: python

I have a function to create image difference hash and stored in a list in Python:

```
import glob
import dhash
from alive_progress import alive_bar
from wand.image import Image

def get_photo_hashes(dir='./'):
    file_list = {}
    imgs = glob.glob(dir + '*.jpg')
    total = len(list(imgs))
    with alive_bar(total) as bar:
        for i in imgs:
            with Image(filename=i) as image:
                row, col = dhash.dhash_row_col(image)
            hash_val = dhash.format_hex(row, col)
            file_list[i] = hash_val
            bar()
    return file_list
```

The performance of hashing a folder of 10,000 500kb - 1MB JPEG images are surprisingly slow, around 2 hashes per second. How can I enhance the performance of this function? Thanks.

Comment: Folders with that many files have a rather long access time already.

Comment: Have you tried to use `pillow` instead? I guess that image resizing takes most of this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like @JCaesar answer a lot, and decided to have a play with it. I created 1,000 JPEGs of around 500kB each with:

```
parallel magick -size 640x480 xc: +noise random {}.jpg ::: {1..1000}
```

Then I tried the code from his answer using Wand, and got 21.3s for 1000 images. I then switched to PIL, and using the same images, the time dropped to 9.6s. I then had a think and realised that the Perceptual hash algorithm converts the image to greyscale and shrinks it to 8x8 pixels - and that the JPEG library has a *"shrink-on-load"* feature which you can use in PIL if you call `Image.draft(newMode,newSize)`. That reduces the time to load and also the amount of I/O needed. Enabling that feature further reduces the time to 6s for the same images. The code looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
    
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/70709538/2836621
    
import dhash
import glob
from PIL import Image
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Manager
    
PATH = '*.jpg'
    
def makehash(t):
    filename, d = t
    with Image.open(filename) as image:
        image.draft('L', (32,32))
        row, col = dhash.dhash_row_col(image)
        d[filename] = dhash.format_hex(row, col)
 
def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        d = manager.dict()
        with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(makehash, [(jpg, d) for jpg in glob.glob(PATH)])
        print(d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I'd use simple [`Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) here with [`Pool.imap_unordered()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap_unordered) as we don't really need order. Also I'd return pair filename-hash from `makehash()` instead of updating shared dictionary which could be passed into `dict()` constructor after. Or if you want to stay with `ProcessPoolExecutor` there's a way to consume results immediately using `executor.submit()` with `as_completed()`. Small edits could add some performance.

Comment: Something like [this](https://tio.run/##bVOxboMwEN35CqsLpkIMyVJVytAhUiNlYOgWRRaBA9xiGxmjJKr67fRsIA5tPNjc3bt3z3emvZpayfVLq4eBi1ZpQ4o66@pgMqpGnYJSK0HS3Z5Mzp3IKhi9uZJ5rzVIk5S96TV0MyjVKoeuS5VqthfIe6N0TLKO5Uq0DRgoAoIrSN8@3smGhM/JZ1uFo6@AkojsC6wQWvIGZCYgenXBMzf1KCBRLUgfRm4sjf4RZ5czk0JnpaHhPowJXa/i9SqKbgitzjHeoUEF7tqJ2xm6UWdDHcEdGvCGckKWSovMsBoudGZB5KSdSzrpLZD6@8dLf9AW6rTDZHn5c0ORYA4mXX8S3NC5OzHx7bl9EpTmDS7dEBO7Udvt6OgrWKCrYmH3w6FT8cjLcQkz62ZWdxjP4wJm9HWZZ5fVe8tLMLVvDI0WMLjk0BqydQdX0vXlP1OruTT0ycNUjo8QCnKuUR@GXYu5rJ58f2ICf2o13QPq4jAnHFGr@xOWVYsoCHhJGLMYxsgG3y5jduKMhSPfOP5h@AU). *(haven't tested)*

Comment: @OlvinRoght Cool - thank you for sharing your insights and experience - I'm always keen to learn. Don't be shy, add your latest/greatest code as another answer for all to see, try and learn from.

Comment: Actually I've added it as comment, cause I have not possibility right now to test real difference in performance between your original answer and code I've added. Will be glad if you can test are there any performance boost.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I tried your suggested code, and it was indeed around 0.2s faster on average, so I deduce that the bulk of the time is actually resizing the images and calculating the hash rather than the collating of the results in the Manager-hosted dict. Many thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Actually, I'm surprised even with 0.2s, I expected to see no visible boost at all :D The main improvement in my code is that "free" process won't wait previous images to finish processing as it does not rely on order. Theoretically if images won't be equal size this improvement will be more useful.

Answer (score 2):

Multiprocessing would ideal for this as the hashing is CPU intensive.

Here's what I suggest:

```
import dhash
import glob
from wand.image import Image
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Manager

PATH = '*.jpg'

def makehash(t):
    filename, d = t
    with Image(filename=filename) as image:
        row, col = dhash.dhash_row_col(image)
        d[filename] = dhash.format_hex(row, col)

def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        d = manager.dict()
        with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(makehash, [(jpg, d) for jpg in glob.glob(PATH)])
        print(d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Some stats:

I have a folder containing 129 JPGs. The average size of each file is >12MB. The net processing time is ~19s

Comment: Very elegant technique - thanks for sharing.