# Logic put in a Python class runs indefinitely

Tags: python

I have logic for bulk calculating image hash.

**Script 1**

```
import dhash
import glob
from PIL import Image
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Manager
    
PATH = '*.jpg'
    
def makehash(t):
    filename, d = t
    with Image.open(filename) as image:
        image.draft('L', (32,32))
        row, col = dhash.dhash_row_col(image)
        d[filename] = dhash.format_hex(row, col)
 
def main():
    with Manager() as manager:
        d = manager.dict()
        with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(makehash, [(jpg, d) for jpg in glob.glob(PATH)])
        print(d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For around 10,000 JPEGs, it runs for less than a minute. However, if I put the logic into a class, it runs indefinitely:

```
import numpy
import cv2
import glob
import os
import dhash
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from datetime import timedelta
from wand.image import Image
from itertools import chain
from alive_progress import alive_bar
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from multiprocessing import Manager

FOLDER_DUPLICATE = 'duplicate'

def listdir_nohidden(path):
    return glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*'))


def create_dir(directory):
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)


def print_elapsed(sec):
    print("Elapsed Time: ", timedelta(seconds=sec))


class ImgToolkit:
    file_list = {}

    def __init__(self):
        # initialize something
        with Manager() as manager:
            self.file_list = manager.dict()
        print("loaded")

    def find_duplicates(self):
        if os.path.exists(FOLDER_DUPLICATE) and listdir_nohidden(FOLDER_DUPLICATE):
            print("ERROR: Duplicate folder exists and not empty. Halting")
        else:
            start = timer()

            print("Phase 1 - Hashing")
            imgs = glob.glob('*.jpg')

            def get_photo_hashes_pillow(t):
                filename, self.file_list = t
                with Image.open(filename) as image:
                    image.draft('L', (32, 32))
                    row, col = dhash.dhash_row_col(image)
                    self.file_list[filename] = dhash.format_hex(row, col)

            with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
                executor.map(get_photo_hashes_pillow, [(jpg, self.file_list) for jpg in imgs])
            print(self.file_list)

            end = timer()
            print_elapsed(end-start)
```

And I use the class as follow:

```
from imgtoolkit import imgtoolkit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    kit = imgtoolkit.ImgToolkit()
    kit.find_duplicates()
```

What did I miss? I am quite new in Python.

---

**UPDATE**

I found that the function `get_photo_hashes_pillow` never get called, as I put a `print()` line in the 1st line of function. But why?

Comment: how do you use the class(please also paste that part of code)?

Comment: Why downvote? The question should be clear enough.

Comment: i'm note downvoter, but have you tried comparing `imgs` of two version have same items?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same folder, thus the result of the `imgs` are the same.

Comment: This class design doesn't make very much sense to me. [What is a ImgToolkit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0)? One difference I notice is that `manager` will be closed by the end of the instance `__init__`. Is the `.dict()` result still valid and usable after that? Another difference is that originally, in `filename, d = t`, `d` was a local variable for `makehash`; now `filename, self.file_list = t` reassigns `self.file_list` from the data created by the list comprehension. Presumably this just replaces the value with itself, but maybe that's a problem with multithreading?

Comment: Do you actually need multithreading for this? Does it actually *help*? This looks like something that ought to be I/O bound.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I followed the recommendation from my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70708949/slow-performance-in-hashing-images-in-python), as the original hashing speed is too slow. Running hashing in parallel might help in my opinion.

Comment: The reason of making a class is that I want to build a Python package. Isn't it the right way to do so?

Comment: No, classes have *nothing to do with* packaging. Classes are how you *define a data type*, just like in basically any other language that has them. For packaging, you need a *package*, which entails making a folder with .py files in it (which produce the *modules* of the package). The people who maintain `pip` also provide a [full guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/) on packaging in Python. There's also a popular [article series](https://cjolowicz.github.io/posts/hypermodern-python-01-setup/) going over best practices for current tools.

Comment: "the original hashing speed is too slow." It might have been CPU-bound originally, but I wouldn't be surprised if the `image.draft` call reverses that.

Comment: thanks. Therefore my logic needs to be rewritten, without multithreading, without class. Actually I'm following this [guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-package-your-python-code-df5a7739ab2e). The author uses Class.